# SharePoint 365 public site masterpage & stylesheet not showing

Tags: master-page, office-365, style-library

I have just made a SharePoint 365 public site live, but when I view the site the masterpage & style library aren't being pulled through. Here's the link to the site: http://365public.arthaus-beta.com/

I have checked the permissions on the style library & this is what I'm presented with:
[image]

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Did you publish (a major version of) the new files?

Comment: I thought i had, but after doing so again, everything seems to be working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should answer the question and mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.